# Image From Music Library Not Showing in UWP app

Tags: windows, xaml, uwp

I'm new to UWP development & I'm just showing image in my app from the Music Library.

Infact, I have added Music Library in the app's "Capabilities" & I can confirm that I have access to Music Library as I can read & write files in it.

**But when I try to load a image in XAML, it just does not shows...**

```xml
<Image Height="200" Width="200" Source="C:/Users/Alex Mercer/Music/Album/albumArt.png" />
```

Please help me understand & solve the problem.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: A UWP application can't just reach out and access random files in the file system. If you want to access the Music Library you're going to have to do it through the provided interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although we enable the corresponding capabilities, accessing files through paths is still strictly restricted in UWP.

In fact, it is not a good idea to write the full path in XAML, because you cannot guarantee that the path must exist on the device where the application is installed.

To display the pictures in the music library, you can do this:

**xaml**

```xml
<Image Height="200" Width="200" x:Name="AlbumImage" Loaded="AlbumImage_Loaded"/>
```

**xaml.cs**

```cs
private async void AlbumImage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var albumFolder = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFolderAsync("Album");
        var albumPic = await albumFolder.GetFileAsync("albumArt.png");

        var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        using (var stream = await albumPic.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
        {
            await bitmap.SetSourceAsync(stream);
        }
        AlbumImage.Source = bitmap;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {
        // File or Folder not found
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
```